# How to show specific elements of webpage in webview in android?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

So i know I can manipulate webspages in a webview by hiding elements i don't want to be seen.

What i'm trying to figure out is... is it possible to just show one element vs. NOT showing other elements?

Essentially, there are times when I don't know which elements there are, but I will always know that a specific element exists, so it's easier for me to just show that one.

I tried:

```
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByClassName('content-container')");
```

However it still shows the whole site.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to fetch the data in the form of json from the website and manually manipulate them into the app. 
Go through [WordPress to Android App using WP REST API Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wordpress-to-android-app-tutorial/) to get the details